# Connect azure key vault getting error is "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: ' in C#

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault, app-id, azure-app-registration

Error message::

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.'SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

This is the code used to connect to Azure Keyvault from local machine.

```
public static async Task PrivacyAsync()
{
        string Client_Id = "xxxxxxxx";
        string Client_Secret = "xxxxxx";
        var kvUri = "xxxx";

        var client = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
            async (string auth, string res, string scope) =>
            {
                var authcontext = new AuthenticationContext(auth);
                var credential = new ClientCredential(Client_Id, Client_Secret);
                AuthenticationResult result = await authcontext.AcquireTokenAsync(res, credential);

                if (res == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("token failed");

                   
                }
                return result.AccessToken;
            }
            ));

        var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(kvUri, "xxxxxx");
        Console.WriteLine("secret success full read"+secret.Value);
        Console.ReadLine();
    
        //var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        //await client.SetSecretAsync("test0311", "hello");
        
}
```

Expected result:

Blob storage connection string value stored into Keyvault secret. I need to fetch blob storage connection string value from Keyvault secret using C# code.

Comment: What is the .NET version of your App?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you have given necessary permissions to access the Azure `KeyVault` Secrets.
- In `Azure Active Directory` => `App Registration` => `Authentication`, check the `implicit` options.

[image]

- In Access Policies, provide the below permissions and select the same registered App.

[image]

[image]

The code which you have provided is Obsolete(old).

When I tried with your code, I got the below warning.

[image]

- I have added `[Obselete]`.

[image]

- I have tried with the below 2 codes and it worked for me.

***Code 1:***

```cs
    string Client_Id = "**********";
    string Client_Secret = "**********";
    string tenantID = "**********";
    var kvUri = "https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/";


    string secretName = "BlobConnection";

    var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantID, Client_Id, Client_Secret);
    var client1 = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), credential);

    KeyVaultSecret secret = client1.GetSecret(secretName);

    Console.WriteLine("secret success full read" + secret.Value);
```

***OR***

Install the latest versions of the below `NuGet Packages`.

```cs
 Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
 Azure.Identity
```

***Code 2 :***

```cs
public static async Task PrivacyAsync()
 {              
    var kvUri = "https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/";      
    var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
    var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync("BlobConnection");
    Console.WriteLine("secret success full read" + secret.Value.Value);
    Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

[image]